# Can C# 4.0 variance help me call a base class constructor with an upcast?

Tags: c#, generic-variance

I was reading a bit on generic variance and I don't have a full understanding of it yet but I'd like to know if it makes something like the following possible?

```
class A<T> { }

class B { }

class C : B { }

class My1  {
    public My1(A<B> lessDerivedTemplateParameter)
    {
    }
}

class My2 : My1 {
    public My2(A<C> moreDerivedTemplateParameter)
        : base(moreDerivedTemplateParameter) // <-- compile error here, cannot convert
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not as fluent in the generic variance as i would like to be, hence this a comment, not an answer, but i think you need to define `A<T>` as `A<out T>` to make this compile.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I believe that is only allowed for interfaces.

Comment: interesting, i did your suggestion plus had to make A and interface, then it compiles...i'll keep going and see if I can get the same result I was after, thanks...

Comment: Generic variance does not work with classes in C#. If `A<T>` were an interface, then you can declare it as `A<out T>`, and then you could call the base constructor the way you want.

Comment: @Douglas thanks, taught me something too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because while `C` inherits from `B`, `A<C>` does not inherit from `A<B>`.

To understand why this is the case, imagine if `A<T>` were instead `List<T>`:

```
class B { }

class C : B { }

class D : B { }

class My1  {
    public My1(List<B> lessDerivedTemplateParameter)
    {
       // This is totally legal
       lessDerivedTemplateParameter.Add(new D());
    }
}

class My2 : My1 {
    public My2(List<C> moreDerivedTemplateParameter)
        // if this were allowed, then My1 could add a D to a list of Bs
        : base(moreDerivedTemplateParameter)
    {
    }
}
```

Now on the other hand, this is legal:

```
interface IA<out T> { 
    public T GetSome();
}

class B { }

class C : B { }

class D : B { }

class My1  {
    public My1(IA<B> lessDerivedTemplateParameter)
    {
       // This is totally legal
       var someB = lessDerivedTemplateParameter.GetSome();
    }
}

class My2 : My1 {
    public My2(IA<C> moreDerivedTemplateParameter)
        // This is allowed, because an A<C> only *produces* C's (which are also B's)
        // so the base class (which consumes B's, and doesnt care if they are C's) 
        // can use an IA<C>
        : base(moreDerivedTemplateParameter)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but misses the point of the question. He *knows* that the current setup doesn't work, and wants to know if he can take advantage of variance to change that situation. You've just restated what he already knows.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare A as an interface with a contravariant type parameter and it will compile:

```
internal interface A<out T>
    {
    }

    internal class B
    {
    }

    internal class C : B
    {
    }

    internal class My1
    {
    public My1(A<B> lessDerivedTemplateParameter)
    {
    }
}

internal class My2 : My1
{
    public My2(A<C> moreDerivedTemplateParameter)
        : base(moreDerivedTemplateParameter) 
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: the critical thing to note here is that this constrains A to only producing (and not consuming) type T.

Comment: @ChrisShain, and that is the connection to meaning of `out` right?